# Analog camera possibility?

Tags: camera

I own an Raspberry Pi. Compared to rpicam, an analog camera is cheaper. Is there any possibility to connect an analog camera to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hello and welcome. The Raspberry Pi has no on-board interface for analog cameras. So you will need to use additional hardware, e.g. a framegrabber as flakeshake's answer suggests. If you have a certain camera in mind, feel free to share the details as those might be of relevance for a best fitting answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an USB framegrabber. Note that not all
models work well on the Pi , especially "Easycap" has problems since they contain wildly different chipsets. Even the vendors do not know which chipsets they sell.

Comment: I'll check the camera and come back with the specification link.